# live data cannot be observed in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a viewmodel which is used by two fragments. Everything is working fine between these components. Now to the problem, the viewmodel uses a SavedStateHandle to save states for data  like this :

```
class MediaFilesViewModelState(
private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) {
var mediaFilesList = savedStateHandle
    .getLiveData<List<MediaFile>>(
        "mediaFilesList"
    )
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["mediaFilesList"] = value
    }

fun updateMediaFilesList(list: List<MediaFile>) {
    this.mediaFilesList.value = list
}

var subCategoryMainNumber = savedStateHandle
    .get<Int>(
        "subCategoryMainNumber"
    )
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["subCategoryMainNumber"] = value
    }

fun updateSubCategoryMainNumber(id: Int) {
    this.subCategoryMainNumber = id
}


var currentPosition = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Long>("currentPosition")
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["currentPosition"] = value
    }
fun updateCurrentPosition(currentPosition: Long) {
    this.currentPosition.value = currentPosition
}


var duration = savedStateHandle.get<Long>("duration") ?: 0L
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["duration"] = value
    }

fun updateDuration(duration: Long) {
    this.duration = duration
}

var durationString = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("durationString")
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["durationString"] = value
    }
fun updateDurationString(progressString: String) {
    this.durationString.value = progressString
}

var progress = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Float>("progress")
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["progress"] = value
    }
fun updateProgress(progress: Float) {
    this.progress.value = progress
}
var progressString = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("progressString")
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["progressString"] = value
    }
fun updateProgressString(progressString: String) {
    this.progressString.value = progressString
}
var isPlaying = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Boolean>("isPlaying")
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["isPlaying"] = value
    }
fun updateIsPlaying(isPlaying: Boolean) {
    this.isPlaying.value = isPlaying
}
private val dummyFile = MediaFile(
    audioFileId = 0,
    path = "",
    displayName = "dummyFile",
    artist = "",
    duration = 0,
)

var playingFileName = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("playingFileName")
    private set(value) {
        field = value
        savedStateHandle["playingFileName"] = value
    }
fun updatePlayingFileName(mediaFile: String) {
    this.playingFileName.value = mediaFile
}
```

all live data are being observed in a fragment like this :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentComandCenterBinding.bind(view)

    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((view.parent) as View)
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
    val metric = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    val initialHeight = (metric.heightPixels * 0.25).toInt()
    bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = initialHeight

    //view functions
    subscribeToObservers()



    binding.apply {

        mediaFilesViewModel.state.playingFileName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            println("displayName2: ${it}")
            tvMediaName.text = it
        }

        mediaFilesViewModel.state.durationString.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            tvDuration.text = it
        }
        mediaFilesViewModel.state.progressString.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

            tvCurrentProgress.text = it
        }



        mediaFilesViewModel.state.isPlaying.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (it) {
                btnPlayPauseAnimation(true)
            } else {
                btnPlayPauseAnimation(false)
            }
            isPlaying = it
        }


        mediaFilesViewModel.state.progress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            progressBar.progress = it.toInt()
        }
        progressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            var pb_position = 0
            override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                pb_position = p1
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                // if (playingMediaFile != null) {
                mediaFilesViewModel.onEvent(
                    MediaFilesViewModelEvents.OnSeekTo(
                        pb_position.toLong()
                    )
                )
                // }
            }

        })
}
```

every live data introduced in last part can and is observed here except for playingFileName.
I am sure that it receives data and it can be observed in the other fragment. but in this one it does nothing